# Ошибка отрисовки кнопки LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

По видеоурокам пытаюсь научиться создавать кнопки ,но постоянно вылетает ошибка 
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: style cannot be null.**

вот код Кнопки

```
public class GameButton extends Stage {

public GameButton(){
    super(new FitViewport(20, 40));
    try {
        Button p = new Button(Resyrsi.sButtonStyle);
        p.setBounds(20, 20, 2, 2);

        addActor(p);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Код стиля для кнопки

```
public class Resyrsi {

public static Button.ButtonStyle sButtonStyle ;
public static Skin skin;

public static void load(){
    skin = new Skin();

    skin.addRegions(new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("fsdgfd.atlas")));

    sButtonStyle = new Button.ButtonStyle();
    sButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("start");
}
```

и вот так пытаюсь нарисовать но никак не получается

```
GameButton mGameButton;

public MyGdxGame(final Main main) {
    mGameButton = new GameButton();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    mStage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch , "Hеlloy" , 300 , 300);
    batch.end();
    mStage.act(delta);
    mStage.draw();

    mGameButton.act(delta);
    mGameButton.draw();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так вы же не вызываете инициализацию кнопки `sButtonStyle` и сразу передаете её, когда она `null`.

```
public class GameButton extends Stage {

public GameButton(){
    super(new FitViewport(20, 40));
    Resyrsi.load(); // Вот это добавьте в код
    try {
        Button p = new Button(Resyrsi.sButtonStyle);
        p.setBounds(20, 20, 2, 2);

        addActor(p);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```